# Is this possible to predict the lottery numbers (not the most accurate)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for the machine learning correct approach for predicting the lottery numbers, not the most accurate answer but at least we have some predicted output. I am implementing the regression based and neural network models for this. Is their any specific approach which follows this?

Comment: The lottery numbers are random, so unless it's not random, I think it's totally impossible to predict

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible. The lottery numbers are random - actually to be more specific, the system is chaotic. You would require the initial configuration (positions etc) to insane (possibly infinite) precision to be able to make any predictions. Basically, don't even try it.